# Sending something to SocketInputStream before Socket.getInputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I ran into a weird error just now. I was playing around with Serializable objects, I was using two objects, communicating with each other over a Socket connection. The Two applications are the same (Peer 2 peer) but there are two instances running and trying to communicate.

The problems seemed to revolve around getting an `ObjectInputStream` from the sockets `InputStream`. My error occurred at the `reader = new ObjectInputSream(cliIn)`, I was thrown a SocketTimeoutException (which is weird in it self, I would have expected that at the `read()` not when decorating my stream. Below is how I attempted to do things.

```
Socket clientSocket;
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(aHostIP), aPort);
clientSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);

InputStream cliIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream reader = null;
reader = new ObjectInputStream(cliIn); // <--- Error here
ObjectOutputStream writer;
writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
     clientSocket.getOutputStream()
));

writer.writeObject(new Request(aPort));
writer.flush();
```

What's weird is that if I moved the creation of the `ObjectInputStream` until after I had written to the `OutputStream` (at which point the other object would have responded to the request), then there was no more error.

```
Socket clientSocket;
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(aHostIP), aPort);
clientSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);   

ObjectOutputStream writer;
writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
     clientSocket.getOutputStream()
));

writer.writeObject(new Request(aPort));
writer.flush();

InputStream cliIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream reader = null;
reader = new ObjectInputStream(cliIn); // <--- No more error
```

The other (responding side) looks like this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(aConnection.getInputStream());
Object req = in.readObject();
SysIO.print("FROM OBJECT! : " + req.toString());
SysIO.print("FROM OBJECT! Port: " + ((Request) req).getPort());

Request res = new Request(15);

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
      new BufferedOutputStream(aConnection.getOutputStream()));
out.writeObject(res);
out.flush();
```

It now works but I'd love to know what the issue was for future reference. I can see that it might be difficult to say exactly but maybe you have some pointers for further investigations, concurrency issues, am I using the Sockets or Buffers wrong?

(I have left out some error handling to make it somewhat clearer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the [`ObjectInputStream` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)):

> ```
> public ObjectInputStream(InputStream in)
>                   throws IOException
> ```
>
> Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. **A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header**.
>
> If a security manager is installed, this constructor will check for the "enableSubclassImplementation" SerializablePermission when invoked directly or indirectly by the constructor of a subclass which overrides the ObjectInputStream.readFields or ObjectInputStream.readUnshared methods.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `in` - input stream to read from
>
> Throws:
>
> `StreamCorruptedException` - if the stream header is incorrect
>
> **`IOException` - if an I/O error occurs while reading stream header**
>
> `SecurityException` - if untrusted subclass illegally overrides security-sensitive methods
>
> `NullPointerException` - if `in` is null

During construction, the stream is trying to read a serialization header from the socket, but the socket read times out because the other party hasn't sent any serialized object yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So it's this read to get the head that throws the `SocketTimeoutException`? As far as I understand there is no way of checking with 100% certainty whether there buffer is empty. Is such an action necessary or is it enough that I match the opening of input and output stream with the server as above? (as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21075566/2671179)?)

Comment: Yes, the socket timeout is due to the reading of the stream header, since there is no header available to read at that time. Your client can't create a `ObjectInputStream` until the server is sending its `ObjectOutputStream` header, which does not happen until after your client sends its `ObjectOutputStream` first.