# readUTF and writeUTF greater than 65535

Tags: java, network-programming, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

My mmorpg game server has a feature that has finally surpassed the 65535 length limit of sending "string updates" to the client.  I was using the readUTF() and writeUTF() methods.  I have since replaced them with:

CLIENT reading:

```
//incommingReply = GameActivity.commandIn.readUTF();  //65535 length limit
int length = GameActivity.commandIn.readInt();
byte[] data = new byte[length];
GameActivity.commandIn.readFully(data);
incommingReply = new String(data,"UTF-8");
```

SERVER writing:

```
//commandOut.writeUTF(request);  //65535 length limit
byte[] b = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
commandOut.writeInt(b.length);
commandOut.write(b);
commandOut.flush();
```

Ever since changing, players are experiencing more disconnections due to "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort".  I am struggling to troubleshoot this.  Is there a better way to send long Strings back and forth?

Example error:
[image]

Addendum (other pertinent code):

```
GameActivity.sC = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();
GameActivity.sC.setSoTimeout(connectTimeout);
GameActivity.sC.connect(new InetSocketAddress(GameActivity.PROD_IP, GameActivity.PROD_PORT), connectTimeout);
...
GameActivity.commandIn = new DataInputStream(GameActivity.sC.getInputStream()); //create input-stream for a command socket
GameActivity.commandOut = new DataOutputStream(GameActivity.sC.getOutputStream()); //create output-stream for a command socket
```

Stack Trace:

```
E  MCR Exception
E  Exception: java.io.EOFException
E  stack trace: 
   java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:205)
   java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:394)
   com.kisnardonline.kisnardonline.MyCommandReceiver.run(MyCommandReceiver.java:251)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

*edit2* - changing to readObject() has not solved the problem

[image]

Comment: Which line of code got the exception? NB I would certainly use `BufferedInput/OutputStreams` around those socket streams underneath the `DataInput/OutputStreams`.

Comment: It's not showing me which line which is weird.  No stack trace.  Can you expand more on your idea or link sample code?

Comment: Err, `new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))`? and `new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))`? and *why* is there no stack trace? Can't you fix that? It's your code.

Comment: Yeah was too tired.  Messing with stack trace now.  How does wrapping buffered streams help?  Would love to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: It helps with performance, as you are making fewer system calls. Impossible to help you further without a stack trace. However I will (1) ask whether you are doing any other I/O with these streams other than as shown above, and if so (2) have you checked it for symmetry; and (3) I will suggest that you could try using `ObjectInput/OutputStream` and `read/writeObject()` instead of `DataInput/OutputStream` and `read/writeUTF()`. That way you still have single-line sends and receives and it will handle small or large strings automatically.

Comment: I added a stack trace.  I changed to Object as you recommended and now my login isnt working.  It just sits stuck at this line (on server side).  

      //v1./v2. unable to do longer strings, 65535 length limit && getting random disconnects - java.io.EOFException
      //DataInputStream commandIn = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream()); //create input-stream for a command socket
      //v3. use object intput/output stream
      ObjectInputStream commandIn = new ObjectInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream()); //create input-stream for a command socket

Comment: Flipped the order of the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream and now it works.  Seems like a deadlock maybe per this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075453/objectinputstream-from-socket-getinputstream)... will do some testing and see if it stops the random disconnects

Comment: Get rid of the Data streams. You don’t need them both.

Comment: Added a stack trace.  I don't have the DataInput/OutputStreams.  I changed them to ObjectInput/OutputStreams.

Comment: `java.io.EOFException` is normal with these `readXXX()` methods. It happens when the peer closes the connection. You should catch it separately and proceed accordingly, not logging it as an error to be investigated. I don't understand how you can be logging an exception in `readObject()` from a method named `commandOut.write`. NB You don't need `String.valueof()`, just a cast to `(String)`. NB (2) We can do without the pictures of text. Post the text: in this case, the code.